# How to open socket in Python with Active/Passive host?

Tags: python, sockets

My goal is to open the socket with a host who is Up.

My initial code with a single host:

```
!/usr/bin/python

import socket

def Socket(host, port):
     # create socket
     s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     try:
             s.connect((str(host), port))
     except Exception as e:
             print("Error Socket not open")

     # Request
     Request = "GET services\n"

     # Send
     s.sendall(Request)
     s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
     data = ""
     while 1:
             buf = s.recv(255)
             if not buf:
                     break
             data += buf
      s.close()
     table = [ line.split(';') for line in data.split('\n')[:-1] ]
     return table;
```

I call this function by

> ```
>     Socket('myhost1', 50000)
> ```

I would like use something like that:

> ```
>     Socket(['myhost1','myhost2'], 50000)
> ```

If the function couldn't open the socket with myhost, i would like use myhost2 to open the socket.

How to do the test if the socket couldn't open with myhost1 ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to simply loop the hosts, and use the first connection that is successful.

```
def Socket(hosts, port):
    # create socket
    sock = connect(hosts, port)

    # Send
    Request = "GET services\n"
    sock.sendall(Request)
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    data = ""
    while 1:
        buf = sock.recv(255)
        if not buf:
            break
        data += buf
    sock.close()
    table = [line.split(';') for line in data.split('\n')[:-1]]
    return table


def connect(hosts, port):
    for host in hosts:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            sock.connect((str(host), port))
        except socket.error:
            # Unable to establish a connection, lets move on to the next host.
            continue
        return sock
    raise Exception('Unable to establish connection')
```

In the new connect method we basically try to establish a connection, and if that fails, try the second address. If all addresses fails, simply raise an exception.